# Next JS 13 - A Server Component import one or multiple Client Component

Tags: reactjs, import, next.js13

I have a server component which is to import 2 client components

`components/test.jsx`

```
'use client'
import React from 'react'

export function Test1() {
  return (
    <div>test1</div>
  )
}


export function Test2() {
  return (
    <div>test2</div>
  )
}
```

The server component only to import the component `Test1` and `Test2` by using `import { Test1, Test2 } from '@/components/test'`

**Problem**
This create an error which can be observed from the console:

```
error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

In contrast, if a component to import the `Test1` and `Test2` is a also a client component with `"use client"` directive, then it would work as expected.

**Question**
Is this an expected behavior from Next or am I missing something?

**Work around solution**
I have to split the file into 2 files in which each component has to use export default:

```
'use client'
import React from 'react'

// This also shows error as the "export default" can't be within the same line
// export default function Test1() {
//   return (
//     <div>test1</div>
//   )
// }

function Test1() {
  return (
    <div>test1</div>
  )
}

export default Test1
```